# Jquery validation error message position for checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery for checkbox validation(atleast one should be checked), here i need to display error message at the end of all checkboxes, but it always display after the label element and moves all checkboxes at the right side, which looks very weird. Below is my html code:

```
           <div>
            <label>Please Select a color:</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="color"  name="color" value="red"> red</input>
                <input type="checkbox" id="color"  name="color" value="green"> green</input>
                <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" value="yellow"> yellow</input>
                <input type="checkbox" id="color"  name="color" value="black"> black</input>
           </div>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to display error message at the right side after the end of all checkboxes without moving form structure.

Thanks in advance..

~Yash

Comment: show the js validation and css

Comment: Hi , here is js validation http://pastebin.com/4T9UB6sU
for css i have not done any modification , thanks for response

Comment: wrap your checkboxes inside div and provide 'clear: both' property to that div.

Comment: Hi , thanks , actually I am getting error message after label wen using this js http://pastebin.com/xijgVZ0E without any errorplacement attribute which is what id ont want. If i use errorplacement (as here http://pastebin.com/4T9UB6sU )it doesnt show any message at all :(

Comment: any help on this would be appreciated , waiting for the response

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
error.appendTo("div");
```

instead of this:

```
 error.appendTo( element.parent("div").next("div"));
```

**Edit**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm" action="">
        <div>
        <label>Please Select a color:</label> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="color"  name="color" value="red"> red</input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="color1"  name="color" value="green"> green</input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="color2" name="color" value="yellow"> yellow</input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="color3"  name="color" value="black"> black</input>
        <span id="errorToShow"></span> // Note this
        </div>
        <button type="submit">save</button>
    </form>
```

script:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
            rules: {
                color: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                color: "select atleast one color"
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "color") {
                    error.appendTo("#errorToShow");
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thats not working , I think is appending error after each div tag , my entire html is full of error messages when I use this "error.appendTo("div");" any other suggestions pls?? as i am very new with jquery , not able to find the solution.

Comment: Hi @chirag , thanks  for the detailed solution but that also seems not working, may be something wrong with my code not sure what because I am exactly doing the same , let me try again

Comment: still error message is displaying before all checkboxes and moves checkboxes towards right :|

Comment: Are getting any kind of error? please provide your html & script that you are trying. so that i can help you further.

Comment: HTML and js are same as provided by u in previous answer , I would have send you the screenshot of my deployment but it not allowing me

Comment: Hi @chirag , have posted an image , pls have a look

Comment: Are you applying any kind of css on validation error text?

Comment: No, I am not, its taking default validation css.

Comment: i think there is the problem in default validation css. do you have online link for that validation css?

Comment: hey thats working now after modifying span tag with 

<span id="errorToShow" style="position: absolute;"></span> 

thanks you sooo much for helping continuously  :)

Comment: thats good. congo. welcome